# INotifyPropertyChanged causes cross-thread error

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Here is my scenarion:

I have a GridControl bound to a BindingList. At first what I was doing was creating a worker thread and access the BindingList directly, but this was throwing a "Cross-thread operation detected", so I followed the guide here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AK2981.aspx

By cloning the original BindingList into the worker thread and changing that one, I got the desired effect. However, I recently implemeneted the INotifyPropertyChanged into the object that is held into the BindingList, and I started getting the error again.

My guess is that the GridView is still listening to the INotifyPropertyChanged from the object.

How can I fix this?

My class:

```
public class Proxy : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @TheGateKeeper. How do you solved the first problem? I have the same problem with the same scenario. But cloning the datasource does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are manipulating the UI from outside of the UI thread (such as from a worker thread), then you need to rejoin the UI thread. You can do this by calling `Invoke` on the UI control. You can test if this is required by using `InvokeRequired`.

The pattern typically used is this:

```
public void ChangeText(string text)
{
   if(this.InvokeRequired)
   {
      this.Invoke(new Action(() => ChangeText(text)));
   }
   else
   {
      label.Text = text;  
   }
}
```

In your case the UI is being manipulated as a result of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so you need to make sure that either you always modify your entity on the UI thread (using the above technique), or use a [generic asynchronous INotifyPropertyChanged helper](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2007/07/generic-asynchronous.html). This is a wrapper around the item being bound. It uses the above technique to ensure the `ChangeProperty` event fires on the UI thread.

Here's a very crude example of a proxy for an `Entity` class. This ensures that the property change event rejoins the UI thread, and keeps the entity itself unmodified. Obviously you'll probably want to implement this more generically using DynamicObject for instance.

```
public class NotificationHelper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ISynchronizeInvoke invokeDelegate;
    private readonly Entity entity;

    public NotificationHelper(ISynchronizeInvoke invokeDelegate, Entity entity)
    {
       this.invokeDelegate = invokeDelegate;
       this.entity = entity;

       entity.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    public string Name
    {
       get { return entity.Name; }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
           if (invokeDelegate.InvokeRequired)
           {
               invokeDelegate.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged),
                                     new[] { sender, e });
               return;
           }
           PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: hmm.... So i need to place this in the INotifyPropertyChanged event? I have updated the question with my class code.

Comment: I've updated to clarify, either only change the bound object on the UI thread, or wrap it in a helper class when binding.

Comment: Didn't use this, but marked it as answer as it provides a lot of detail.

Answer (score 6):

I took a similar approach to TheGateKeeper's eventual solution. However I was binding to many different objects. So I needed something a bit more generic. The solution was to create a wrapper that implemented also ICustomTypeDescriptor. In this way, I do not need to create wrapper properties for everything that can be displayed in the UI.

```
public class SynchronizedNotifyPropertyChanged<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly T _source;
    private readonly ISynchronizeInvoke _syncObject;

    public SynchronizedNotifyPropertyChanged(T source, ISynchronizeInvoke syncObject)
    {
        _source = source;
        _syncObject = syncObject;

        _source.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged(args.PropertyName);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null) return;

        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        _syncObject.BeginInvoke(handler, new object[] { this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName) });
    }

    public T Source { get { return _source; }}

    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor
    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return new AttributeCollection(null);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(typeof(T));
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(typeof (T));
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T));
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(typeof (T));
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(typeof(T));
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(typeof (T), editorBaseType);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(typeof(T));
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(typeof (T), attributes);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof (T));
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T), attributes);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return _source;
    }
    #endregion ICustomTypeDescriptor
}
```

Then in the Ui, I bind to this wrapper using something like:

```
    private void CreateBindings()
    {
        if (_model == null) return;

        var threadSafeModel = new SynchronizedNotifyPropertyChanged<MyViewModel>(_model, this);

        directiveLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", threadSafeModel, "DirectiveText", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
```

MyViewModel has a "DirectiveText" property and implements INotifyPropertyChanged with no special consideration to threading or to the view classes.

Answer (score 2):

I subclassed `BindingList` so I could check for a required `Invoke`. This way my business objects do not have a reference to the UI.

```
public class InvokingBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
  public InvokingBindingList(IList<T> list, Control control = null) : base(list)
  {
    this.Control = control;
  }

  public InvokingBindingList(Control control = null)
  {
    this.Control = control;
  }

  public Control Control { get; set; }

  protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Control?.InvokeRequired == true)
      Control.Invoke(new Action(() => base.OnListChanged(e)));
    else
      base.OnListChanged(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has run into the same problem... I managed to fix it after some hours. Here is what I did:

Basically the problem was that the object implementing INotifyPropertyChanged was living in a worker thread, and this causes problems when accessing the UI thread.

So what I did was pass a reference to the object that needs to be updated to the INotifyPropertyChanged object, and then use invoke on it.

Here is what it looks like:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            //If the Proxy object is living in a non-UI thread, use invoke
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))));
            }
            //Otherwise update directly
            else
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }
    }

    //Use this to reference the object on the UI thread when there is need to
    public Control C
    {
        set { c = value; }
    }
```

From the thread, all I did was:

```
                    prox.c = this;
                    //Logic here
                    prox.c = null;
```

Hope this helps someone!!

Comment: This is a bit dirty as it means your business object has references to UI. Better to use a wrapper class, see the link in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I think you still need to pass a reference to the object one way or the other. `this.Invoke(new Action(() => ChangeText(text)));` for example, would need `this` to be the actual control.

Comment: I am very new to threading so this is all very new to me, I can't even understand that code you linked. I think I will stick to my way for now.

Comment: The idea is the wrapper takes a reference to the control and the object being bound and acts as a proxy for events to rejoin the UI thread. I'll try and update with an example.

Comment: But don't you still need to refernence the object? Isn't it the same as my implementation?

Comment: Maybe you can explain this to me, why is the BindingList able to modify a UI element from a worker thread but not the INotifyPropertyChanged? Is it a bug?

Comment: BindingList cannot modify the UI, the code in the example you provided shows that it's bound within BeginInvoke, which rejoins the UI thread. It's not a bug. If you are modifying a bound entity outside of the UI thread, then the change property event fires outside of the UI thread. Somewhere it needs to be rejoined.

Comment: The example was for the class, I never showed my BindingList. What I did was I copied the bindingList to the thread, and then modified it's content. I never used invoke, and it still updated the main UI.