# Handling realtime data

Tags: c#, multithreading, real-time, code-organization, project-organization

My program will be requesting realtime data from a website.  This data can change at any time, so I need to request it repeatedly and frequently to monitor changes.  The data is to be displayed on a windows form chart as a histogram along with some moving averages.  Based on this information, the user needs to be able to interact with the form to set parameters for a part of the program to take action based on the incoming data.  How should I be handling this data?  My current plan is to have a separate thread collecting the data and writing it to the main form, but I'm unsure how to monitor that data for changes without A) making the interface unresponsive and B) starting another thread.  A is unacceptable for obvious reasons, and if I were to do B I feel like I might as well just throw that code into the thread that's collecting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do in this case is have a worker thread do the polling of the website and queue all of the data it finds into a `ConcurrentQueue`. Then have your UI thread periodically poll this queue for new data. You do *not* want to have that worker thread interacting with the UI thread at all. Do not use `Control.Invoke` or other marshaling techniques for situations like this.

```
public class YourForm : Form
{
  private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  private ConcurrentQueue<YourData> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<YourData>();

  private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
  }

  private void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    YourData item;
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
    {
      // Update the chart here.
    }
  }

  private void Worker()
  {
    CancellationToken cancellation = cts.Token;
    while (!cancellation.WaitHandle.WaitOne(YOUR_POLLING_INTERVAL))
    {
      YourData item = GetData();
      queue.Enqueue(item);
    }
  }   
}
```

The example above is based on WinForms, but the same principals would carry over to WPF as well. The important points in the example are.

- Use a `System.Windows.Timer.Timer` (or equivalent if using WPF) to pull the data items from the queue using `TryDequeue`. Set the tick frequency to something that provides a good balance between refreshing screen quickly, but not so quickly that it dominates the UI thread's processing time.
- Use a task/thread to acquire the data from the website and load it into the queue using `Enqueue`.
- Use the `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel the operation via `Cancel` (which I did not include in the example) and to also drive the polling interval by calling `WaitOne` on the `WaitHandle` provided by the `CancellationToken`.

While using `Control.Invoke` or other marshaling techniques is not necessarily a bad thing it is not the panacea that it is often made out to be either. Here are but a few disadvantages to using this technique.

- It tightly couples the UI and worker threads.
- The worker thread dictates how often the UI should update.
- It is an expensive operation.
- The worker thread has to wait for the UI thread to process the message so throughput is decreased.

The advantages of having the UI thread poll for updates are as follows.

- The UI and worker threads are more loosely coupled. In fact, neither really knows anything about the other.
- The UI thread gets to decide on its own how often the updates are applied. This is really how it should be anyway.
- There are no expensive marshaling operations.
- Neither the UI nor the worker threads have their executions impeded by the other. You get more throughput on both threads.

Comment: I think my entire problem stems from the urge to use .Invoke, but could you explicitly explain why this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is a class to hold the data...

```
class DataContainer
{
    readonly byte[] _dataFromWeb;

    DataContainer(byte[] data)
    {
        _dataFromWeb = data;
    }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataFromWeb[index];
        }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataFromWeb.GetUpperBound(0)+1;
        }
    }
}
```

... and a thread-safe object pointer to an object that houses the data.

```
class SafePointerContainer
{
    static public SafePointerContainer Instance =  new SafePointerContainer();

    public DataContainer _data = null;
    private SafePointerContainer() {}

    public DataContainer Data
    {
        get 
        { 
            lock(this)
            {
                return _data;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock(this)
            {
                _data = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

When the UI thread needs to read the data, it should obtain the pointer (in a thread safe manner) and put it in a local variable.  Then it can use the pointer to access all the member variables at its leisure.

```
DataContainer latestData = SafePointerContainer.Instance.Data;
for (int i=0; i<latestData.Length; i++)
{
    DisplayData(i, latestData[i]);
}
```

When the worker thread needs to update the data, it should instantiate a new instance of the object and then update the pointer (in a thread safe manner) to point to the new instance.  The key is to update the members before setting the pointer.  To force you to do this, I implemented the data using the readonly keyword, meaning that it can only be set in the constructor.

```
DataContainer newData = new DataContainer(dataJustObtainedFromTheWeb);
SafePointerContainer.Instance.Data = newData;
```

Give the above classes meaningful names, and change the contents of DataContainer to accommodate whatever the data is that you're retrieving from the web.  For bonus points, re-implement using generics.  Ta da.

---

### How does the UI thread know the data have changed?

The UI thread can inspect the DataContainer just like any other class or variable.  How does ANY thread know if any variable has changed?  Inspect it, and compare it to the last value.

```
DataContainer _oldData = null;
while(!UserClickedExit())
{
    DataContainer newData = SafePointerContainer.Instance.Data;
    if (newData != _oldData)
    {
        RenderData(newData);
        _oldData = newData;
    }
    else
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
{
```

Comment: Nice answer, but fix up this sentence: ` it should new up a new instance of the object`

Comment: The UI needs to read the data whenever the data is changed.  It should be reflecting the data in realtime.  Only the thread reading the data will know this, though.

Comment: A technical trainer in my organization kept using the expression "new up" instead of instantiate.  I thought all the youngsters were talking like this!  Edited.

Comment: Personally I would have `SafePointerContainer` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to let anyone who cares to know that the data in `Data` has changed instead of poling.

Comment: I think you might run into [thread affinity problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156991/inotifypropertychanged-causes-cross-thread-error) if you did that, Scott.